# Can someone please explain where I am going wrong in the given argument? Is it obvious that $f(m,s)>0$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, parametric-functions, multivalued

I have a two-variable function $f(m,s)$ for real $m>0$ and $s>0$, and as the first picture shows, it seems that it is always positive; on the other hand, I can easily find the minimum of $f(m,s)$ that I denote by $fmin$ below but the second picture shows that this minimum can be negative. Is not this a contradiction? I will be grateful if someone explains where I am going wrong. If $f(m,s)$ is always positive why its minimum is negative? Is it obvious that $f(m,s)>0$?

```
q = 1/3 ArcTan[36 m^2 s^2 - s^4, 6 Sqrt[3] m Abs[-4 m^2 s + s^3]]; (*q\[Element] [-Pi/6, Pi/6]*)

f = 3 m^2 + 2 s^2 - s Sqrt[12 m^2 + s^2] (Cos[q] + Sqrt[3] Sin[q]); (* (Cos[q] + Sqrt[3] Sin[q]) \[Element] [0, Sqrt[3]] implying  that  minimum of f  is  as   follows*)

fmin = 3 m^2 + 2 s^2 - s Sqrt[12 m^2 + s^2]  Sqrt[3] ;

{  Plot3D[f, {m, 0, 10}, {s, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]   ,   
 Plot3D[fmin, {m, 0, 10}, {s, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 50]  }
```

[image]

Comment: Your reasoning about the minimum is wrong. You cannot simply replace a term with its extremal value, and expect to get the same position (or value) of minima. Imagine a simpler example: $f(x) = x^2 - \sin x$. You cannot reason that $\sin x \in [-1,1] \implies f_{min}(x) = x^2 - 1$. `Plot[{x^2 - Sin[x], x^2 - 1}, {x, -2, 2}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
q = 1/3 ArcTan[36 m^2 s^2 - s^4, 6 Sqrt[3] m Abs[-4 m^2 s + s^3]];
```

Your statement that `q ∈ {-Pi/6, Pi/6}` is not correct

```
SetOptions[#, WorkingPrecision -> 20] & /@ {NMinValue, NMaxValue};

{qmin, qmax} = 
 N[#[{q, m > 0, s > 0}, {m, s}] & /@ {NMinValue, NMaxValue}] // Chop

(* {0, 1.0472} *)

RootApproximant[qmax/Pi]*Pi

(* π/3 *)
```

Consequently, `q ∈ {0, Pi/3}`

```
Plot3D[{q, Pi/3}, {m, 0, 10}, {s, 0, 10},
 PlotRange -> {0, Pi/2},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Opacity[0.2]},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 Mesh -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 7]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[s > 0, Limit[q, m -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]]

(* π/3 *)

Assuming[s > 0, Limit[q, m -> s/2]]

(* 0 *)
```

Looking at `f`

```
f = 3 m^2 + 2 s^2 - s Sqrt[12 m^2 + s^2] (Cos[q] + Sqrt[3] Sin[q]); 

SetOptions[NMinValue, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];

fmin = NMinValue[{f, m > 0, s > 0}, {m, s}] // Chop

(* 0 *)

Plot3D[f, {s, 0, 10}, {m, 0, 10},
 PlotRange -> {-1, 5},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 7,
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[s > 0, Limit[f, m -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]]

(* 0 *)

Assuming[s > 0, Limit[f, m -> s] // FullSimplify]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Even though that your argument and also plot confirms the range of $q$ but I am confused about the fact that the range of $ArcTan x\in[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2]$, so, multiplying it by $\frac13$ we get $\frac{\pi}6$ for the maximum; also we have `Limit[  1/3 ArcTan[x], x -> Infinity] (*\[Pi]/6*)`; maybe again I am missing something in my argument

Comment: I agree that the results for `q` are inconsistent with the statement in the documentation for `ArcTan` that "For real z, the results are always in the range -\[Pi]/2 to \[Pi]/2." I would **guess** that in the evaluation, Mathematica wandered into the complex plane and got confused by a branch cut. I will ask Wolfram Tech Support.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: **Wolfram Technical Support Case: 5016828** From the documentation for ArcTan, "ArcTan[x, y] gives the arc tangent of y/x" and "For real z, the results are always in the range -\[Pi]/2 to \[Pi]/2." However, ArcTan[x, y] returns values outside of the interval {-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2} for real arguments

Comment: Wolfram Technical Support replied, "... this is a documentation error. The result of the two-argument form of ArcTan lies in the range [-Pi, Pi]." See also [`wiki: atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)